# Getting Row index of Checked Item in CheckBoxTableViewer In SWT

Tags: java, swt, row, tableviewer

I am implementing SWT CheckBoxTableViewer in my Project. Can somebody please tell me how to get the row index of the selected checked item ?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
   final TableItem [] items = tableViewer.getTable().getItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      if (items[i].getChecked())
       ... handle checked
    }
```

You can use `CheckBoxTableViewer.getCheckedElements()` if you just want the checked objects (which uses a loop similar to the above).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for (int i = 0; i < viewer.getTable().getItemCount(); i++)
{
    if (viewer.getChecked(viewer.getElementAt(i)))
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Getting Row index of Checked Item in CheckBoxTableViewer In SWT

```
public void mouseDown(MouseEvent event) {

    Point point = new Point(event.x, event.y);
    TableItem item = table.getItem(point);
    if (item != null) {

            TableItem items[]=table.getItems();
            for(int i=0;i<table.getItemCount();i++){
            if(items[i].getChecked())
            {
                System.out.println("Row index: "+(i+1));
            }
    }
}
```